# Flutter DropDownButton selection calls all apis on setState

Tags: flutter, dart

For my app, I have dropdown to select year. The moment I select a value, the entire app starts calling various apis, which I guess is happening due to setState. A section of code:

```
 DropdownButton(
            style: const TextStyle(
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
            icon: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
            iconSize: 12,
            iconEnabledColor: Colors.red,
            hint: const Text(
              "MM",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.blueAccent,
              ),
            ),
            items: getYears().map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String prod) {
              return DropdownMenuItem(
                value: prod,
                child: Text(prod),
              );
            }).toList(),
            onChanged: (String? newValue) {
              setState(() {
                year = newValue!;
              });

              print(year);
            },
            value: year,
          ),
```

The api calls for the previous dropdowns are getting called when I change value for this dropdown, even though they are not being touched. Any suggestions how to avoid unnecessary api calls with setState for other dropdowns?

Comment: from code that you provide, nothing api calls in onchage function.
api calls only happend on get items.

Comment: maybe you can try to call api  on initstate, then store as variable. then apply to the dropdown items.  so no need to call api everytime the dropdown get touched

Comment: Also if you are using FutureBuilder/StreamBuilder you can create a future variable then use it

Answer (score 0):

```
listOfTransactionType = await TransactionTypeFromServer.data.response.data
  .map((e) => e.type)
  .toList();
```

notifyListeners();

```
final List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> transactionTypedropdownmenuItems =
    listOfTransactionType
        .map((String value) =>
            DropdownMenuItem<String>(value: value, child: Text(value))).toList();
```

Comment: BRO THIS SHOULD HELP YOU NAVIGATE THAT ISSUE